# open pdf stream file in iframe

Tags: asp.net, pdf, iframe, streaming

I want to open a PDF file in my browser using iframe or object tag or what evere can do so

I have an PDF.aspx page:

```
        Response.Buffer = false; //transmitfile self buffers
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file1.pdf");
        Response.TransmitFile(filepath); 
        Response.End();
```

and this is my iframe in another page:

```
<iframe runat="server" src="PDF.aspx" class="pdfFilePanel_fn" width="99%" height="98%"></iframe>
```

it opens the pdf file not showing it inside the iframe!!!

Any idea or better solution?

Answer (score 3):

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file1.pdf");
```

should be changed to

```
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=file1.pdf");
```

:)

Comment: i have the same problem and i tried this one , it seems to work in iframe but the problem is , the iframe is on maximize.. i have an iframe in some place inside my page , i want it to display in that place only not the whole web page.. do you have any idea on that ?

Comment: From what I remember that piece of code in the ASPX page was enough to let iframe be open inside the iframe which was on its original size, whatever with it has.

So just change the width and height of your ifram to for example 200px then it should be fine

Comment: i resized my iframe .. but still it opens as a browser .. it replaces the whole browser showing the pdf .. not just an iframe in one place inside the page..

Comment: it's ok now .. working now using your code.. Thank you so much :)